# unable to type some characters in adobe acrobat and unable to insert table

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I came across two problems.
first, I am unable to type some specific letter, like upper case R,E,+ and so on, but I can type other upper case letter like upper case T. If I am trying to type, they will leave a square with x in it on the screen
At the same time, I have no problem typing these letter in other medium.

secondly, I am trying to insert a table to the pdf file, but I cant find an option on the edit bar or insert bar. so I have to open microsoft word and make a table there, then change it to pdf format and insert it to he current page, seems rather inefficient. Is there an easy way of doing it?

specs: windows 8.1, lenovo yoga 11s, adobe acrobat pro.

Comment: Could it be that you are expecting too much from Acrobat as a content editor? It is not. Although the editing capabilities have improved considerably, they are for last second edits at best. For serious editing, you do better by going back to the original documents.

Comment: but unable to type upper case seems a bug to me.

Comment: Well, is the font used completely installed on your system? Otherwise, you might actually look at Acrobat DC, where they considerably improved the editing functionality.

Comment: yeah, its OK, I don't exactly need a pdf editing software, I just find it a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to type specific characters when filling a form, then it may be because you have key accelerators enabled.

Try:

1. Edit -> Preferences -> General
2. Turn off (untick) "Use single-key accelerators to access tools"